# Post Hoc tests for ANOVA

Tags: r

I was trying to figure out how to do  post-hoc tests for Two Way ANOVAs and found the following 2 approaches:

1. Do pairwise t-tests (bonferroni corrected) if one finds significance with the ANOVA.
   Link- http://rtutorialseries.blogspot.com/2011/01/r-tutorial-series-two-way-anova-with.html
2. Do TukeyHSD  on an aov model
   Link- http://www.r-bloggers.com/post-hoc-pairwise-comparisons-of-two-way-anova/

Running the data set given in the first example in SPSS gives significant pairwise difference for Treatment and Age (Treatmen and Age were the independent variables) , while using the directions given in the first link didn't give me significant pairwise different for Treatment (only gave for Age).

I have a few questions:

1. Is the first method completely incorrect as hinted in the second link?
2. What is the right way to do Bonferroni corrected post hoc tests for Two Way ANOVA in R?
3. Does anyone know how post hoc tests for SPSS work in the case of Two Way ANOVAs (Univariate analysis)? Especially for Bonferroni corrected tests.

I am new to R, so please let me know if I made a mistake in framing the question; I will try to elucidate as much as I personally can. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is off topic for [so]. You'll get more domain-specific help from the CrossValidated sister site. I have flagged this for attention by a Moderator to migrate the question for you.